# Rust: lazy_static the strings from evdev codes

Tags: rust

So I have this piece of code that produces following error:

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `key_name`
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I want it to evaluate the `Key` range and produce a map of strings, but it fails on the line `map`. I can't seem to set up the ownership right. This is what I came up with:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use evdev::Key;

const KEY_RANGE_START : Key = Key::KEY_ESC;
const KEY_RANGE_END : Key = Key::KEY_SLASH;

const KEY_RANGE_COUNT: u16 = KEY_RANGE_END.code() - KEY_RANGE_START.code();

use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref KEY_NAMES: HashMap<u16, &'static str> = {
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        
        for index in 0..KEY_RANGE_COUNT {
            let code = index+KEY_RANGE_START.code();
            let key = Key::new(code);
            let key_name = format!("{:?}", key);

            let short_key_name = key_name.strip_prefix("KEY_").unwrap();

            map.insert(code, short_key_name.clone());
        }

        map
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`short_key_name` is a `&str` that was borrowed from `key_name`, a `String` allocated inside the loop and which will be dropped at the end of each loop iteration. Thus, it is *not* a `&'static str`.

You can use `Box::leak` to create an allocation that *will* stick around for the rest of the life of the program. (This is reasonable for lazy static initialization, but other uses can easily create a memory leak, as the name suggests!)

```rust
let short_key_name = &*Box::leak(Box::<str>::from(short_key_name));
map.insert(code, short_key_name);
```

This

1. copies the characters of the `&str` into a `Box<str>`,
2. forgets about the existence of the box (so it is never deallocated) and creates an `&'static mut str` to its contents, and
3. converts the `&'static mut str` to an `&'static str`, matching the type needed for the `HashMap`.

Do not use `Box::leak` for any code that runs more than once! As the name says, it leaks!

Comment: Thank you very much, mr Reid. Rust has a bit of a learning curve and you helped me significantly.